# Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred creating block based KVO in swift

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

Entering this (*contrived example*) code

```
import Foundation

protocol ValueProviderProtocol {
    var amount: Int { get }
}

class ValueProvider: NSObject, ValueProviderProtocol {
    @objc dynamic var amount = 0
}

let _provider = ValueProvider()

var provider: ValueProviderProtocol { return _provider }

let subject = provider as! NSObject

let observer = subject.observe(\ValueProviderProtocol.amount, options: [.old, .new]) { (provider, changes) in

}
```

into an Xcode 9 playground, results in this error for the call to subject.observe:

> Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred

It is not clear what is causing the error. What can be done to fix this kind of problem?

Answer (score 6):

The following line:

```
let observer = subject.observe(\ValueProviderProtocol.amount, 
                               options: [.old, .new])
                               { (provider, changes) in
}
```

needs to change in to:

```
let observer = _provider.observe(\.amount,
                                 options: [.old, .new],
                                 changeHandler: { (provider, changes) in

})
```

You can not try to observe on subject since is downcasted to an `NSObject` that does not have the property `amount`. And second `\ValueProviderProtocol.amount` is a partial key path that does not infere value type `\.amount` is a `KeyPath` that inferes keypath